# Installed ubuntu-frame with wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk and only get a gray screen

Tags: ubuntu-core, kiosk

I followed the (relatively simple) instructions in [official documentation to install a web kiosk](https://mir-server.io/docs/make-a-secure-ubuntu-web-kiosk) on a ubuntu-core 22 raspberry pi4.

I only get a gray image and can't set the website to display. It *seems* something to do with wayland missing, but `snap connect wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk:wayland` gives me an error:

```
error: snap "snapd" has no "wayland" interface slots
```

I have tried the magical Google searches but completely at a loss to debug/fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the default display triggered by `dtoverlay` in `/boot/firmware/config.txt` has to be adjusted depending on the display. In my case these settings worked. YMMV:

```
# Config settings specific to arm64
arm_64bit=1
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d-pi4
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-dsi-7inch
dtoverlay=dwc2

[all]
# Disable the raspberry splashl
# disable_splash=1
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d-pi4
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-dsi-7inch
dtoverlay=rpi-backlight
```

Hope this helps someone out there